# SqlDataReader doesn`t obey Cancellation requested while reading large row

Tags: c#, sqldatareader, cancellation, .net-4.6

Please consider this code sample:

```
        const int timeoutInSeconds = 60; // 1 minute
        static readonly CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        public static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                tokenSource.CancelAfter(timeoutInSeconds * 1000);

                Task.WaitAll(ReadLargeFile(), TimeStat());
            }
            catch (AggregateException ex)
            {
                foreach (var e in ex.InnerExceptions)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                tokenSource.Dispose();
            }
        }

        static async Task ReadLargeFile()
        {
            using (var con = new SqlConnection($"some connection string"))
            {
                await con.OpenAsync(tokenSource.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);

                using (var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.TableWithFatRows where Id = 1", con))
                {
                    command.CommandTimeout = timeoutInSeconds;

                    SqlDataReader reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior.Default, tokenSource.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);

                    while (await reader.ReadAsync(tokenSource.Token).ConfigureAwait(false)) // we expect cancellation here
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Finished Read iteration. Checking cancellation ");

                        tokenSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); // but actually we got it here

                        // some work
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        static async Task TimeStat(int secondsDelay = 10)
        {
            try
            {
                while (!tokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"#TotalSeconds: {stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds}");

                    await Task.Delay(new TimeSpan(0, 0, secondsDelay), tokenSource.Token).ConfigureAwait(false); ;
                }
            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Cancellation has been requested. Finishing TimeStat task.");
            }
        }
```

The problem - we have to query very large rows from a table. E.g. 15Mb each.
And usually it takes more than 10min to read a single row.

Question is - How to force `SqlDataReader` to abort/close data retrieval process ?

Currently in code above - `SqlDataReader` just ignores requested cancellation, probably by design.
So the execution gets stuck on data reading process (`await reader.ReadAsync(tokenSource.Token)`) until large row downloads completely and violates All connection/command/cancellationToken timeouts.

Comment: It takes 10 minutes to read a single row? Even given that a row is 15MB, that's still far too long and you've got bigger issues to solve than a cancellation token snafu.

Comment: Try streaming LOB data instead -- i.e. use `CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess` and `.GetBytes()`/`.GetChars()` to actually read the fields. Also, if this is `System.Data.SqlClient` try `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` and vice versa; I expect the latter to have better async support. Do note however that cancellation is always cooperative; testing/requiring hard limits for timeouts isn't possible, and neither the connection *nor* the command timeout are ever relevant for the time needed to transport and process rows once the command has begun returning results, which takes as long as necessary.

Comment: @mason those are just average numbers, it can be 30Mb row and 5min to read from Azure Sql - the idea matters - once data retrieval has begun - no cancellation possible.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks for suggestions. I will check that. We are trying to use as generic code as possible, without analyzing target schema up front. Actually we don`t know target table nature.

Comment: That's no problem in principle, because you have the schema available in the `DataReader` before the read (`.FieldCount`, `.GetFieldType`) so you can write code that reads LOB data in a particular way and regular fields in another way without being specialized to the schema. Worth checking is whether off-the-shelf code like Dapper happens to already do what you want for LOB data (I haven't tested), because if you really want maximum performance out of a `DataReader` you can't beat code generation and you don't want to reinvent that wheel.

Comment: @JeroenMostert In my case - the main target is obeying timeouts. I`m not interested in actual data being read from source. And moreover i`m not the owner of target tables. So i can`t force to use LOB instead of fat XML/NVARCHAR(MAX) etc. types

Comment: Sorry, by "LOB data" I do mean fields of `XML`/`NVARCHAR(MAX)`/`VARBINARY(MAX)` or just `NVARCHAR(big)` types; LOB is not a separate data type nor do I mean changing anything on the database end. I assumed a 15M row contains LOB columns somewhere. You cannot make `DataReader` not read *any* data, because TDS is strictly sequential and the next row won't appear until the columns have been read. If you use `SequentialAccess` I believe you can still use `.Read` without accessing the fields, but I've never tested that scenario.

Comment: Another loose bit of advice: for very large rows, the packet size can make a huge difference -- specifying `Packet Size=32767` in the connection string (the maximum, with a default of 8000) can speed things up considerably. Not directly related to timeouts but it may reduce the need for them.